# How can I prevent memory churn in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I'm putting together a hypothesis tree type algorithm in MATLAB and it is being slowed terribly by memory issues.  The profiler shows all time being spent just writing into arrays.

The algorithm keeps a list of hypotheses with information about them in an array of structs.  The issue is related to 3D arrays (not big) within the hypothesis:

```
H(x).someInfo(a,b,c)
```

Each iteration, some hypotheses are discarded:

```
H = H(keepIndices);
```

And the ones that remain are expanded and updated:

```
Hin = H;
H(N*length(H)) = H(1);  % Pre-alloc?
count = 0;
for x = 1:length(Hin)
  for y = 1:N
    count = count + 1;
    H(count) = Hin(x);
    ...  % Computations
    H(count).someInfo(:,:,a) = M;  % Much time spent here
  end
end
```

The profiler indicates huge amounts of time spent just doing the write (note comment).  "someInfo" is preallocated so is not itself growing dynamically, but it is getting copied around.

Can anyone suggest a way to achieve this type of functionality without getting crossways with inefficiencies in the way MATLAB deals with memory?  Not blaming MATLAB, but its flexibility makes this harder than it would be in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the access pattern to `someInfo` is always the same, you could turn it into a cell array of 2D matrices. You'll find that

```
H(count).someInfo{a} = M;
```

is faster than

```
H(count).someInfo(:,:,a) = M;
```

because the array data is not copied over, only the reference to the data is.

---

...and if that is the case, you might want to do

```
H{count,a} = M;
```

Note that the fewer levels of indexing (you have 3!), the faster it is.

Comment: I can give that a shot.  I've had bad luck with the speed of cells in the past.  I thought it made sense they'd be slow since the type inside them is arbitrary.  Even though my array is 3D, it is pre-allocated and fixed size.

Comment: I haven't timed this explicitly, but not needing to copy data is an advantage, especially for larger `M`. From experience I know that complicated indexing is expensive. In this case it seems to be detrimental to performance, so simplifying that statement is the first thing to try.